# Tornado user input error catching

Tags: python, exception, tornado

I am working on a Tornado app.  It has CRUD functions in a file called api.py, and the relevant bits of that are show here:

```
class UserEditException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg

def create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password, session = None):

  others_with_same_email = session.query(MyAppUser).filter(MyAppUser.email.like(email)).all()
  if others_with_same_email is not None:
    raise UserEditException('Already another account with that email address.')
```

This is called by app.py, which contains the actual Handlers, including for the page to Create a new User. The relevent bits of app.py are shown here:

```
import api

class CreateUserHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.render(
      local_templates + "/create_user.html",
      user_msg = 'Enter new user attributes, including an email address not already in use.',
    )

  def post(self):
    user_msg = '' #currently there are no problems found with inputs
    password = self.get_argument("password") 
    email = self.get_argument("email")
    first_name = self.get_argument("first_name",default=None)
    last_name = self.get_argument("last_name",default=None)
    if user_msg == '':
      try:
        new_user = api.create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password, agent_uuid = self.current_user)
      except api.UserEditException, err:
        user_msg = str(err)
      else:
        user_msg = 'The new user,'+new_user['first_name']+' '+new_user['last_name']+' ('+new_user['email']+') has been created successfully.'

    self.render(
      local_templates + "/create_user.html",
      first_name = first_name,
      last_name = last_name,
      email = email,
      user_msg = user_msg,
    )
```

When I enter an email that is already in use (i.e. intentionally trigger an error in user creation), I know that in api.py it is triggering the UserEditException, because the message 'Already another account with that email address.' is being written to the server.  Then the program crashes.  Instead I want the UserEditException caught, and the error message put into "user_msg", to be displayed to the web page.  Can you point what I might be doing wrong in trying to catch this kind of error?  Thanks.

Comment: python version is 2.7.3.  It does not look like `api.UserEditException as err` gives any different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.  Sorry, it appears that in my attempt to simplify the code as much as possible for this question, I left out the most important line.  The `create_user` function had a "transaction_op" decorator, which handled things like rolling back the transaction if there was an error.  However, this decorator therefore was catching the exception, and not re-raising it.  Hence, I couldn't catch it in my Handler, because by the time it left the `create_user` function the exception was already caught.

Moral of the story: if something inexplicable is happening between one function and the code that calls it, be suspicious of the function's decorators.